# JTable refreshes only when i call new instance of GUI();

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, refresh

I have simple JTable app which add data only if i use 'new GUI()' in my buttonListener method. Otherwise doesn't work. I have tried use every FireTable... method in every place in this code. Also tried mainFrame/mainPanel.repaint(); table.revalidate();

Main class

```
public class AddressBook {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try 
    { 
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");  
        new GUI();
    }   
    catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println("GUI loading error..");
    }
}
}
```

GUI() class

```
    public GUI() {

    /** Main Frame, Panels, Borders */
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Address Book");
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(borderOffset, borderOffset, borderOffset, borderOffset));   // up, left, down, right
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    tablePanel = new JPanel();
    tablePanel.setLayout((new BoxLayout(tablePanel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)));

    buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel.setLayout((new BoxLayout(buttonsPanel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)));

    /** Head of table */
    model = new MyTableModel();
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 50));

    /** Heart of table */
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    /** Title of app */
    titleLabel = new JLabel("Address Book");
    titleLabel.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 15));
    titleLabel.setForeground(Color.GRAY);

    /** Buttons */
    final int BUTTONS_WIDTH = 130;
    final int BUTTONS_HEIGHT = 40;
    addButton = new JButton("Add new person");
    addButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BUTTONS_WIDTH, BUTTONS_HEIGHT));
    addButton.addActionListener(new addButtonListener());
    editButton = new JButton("Edit person");
    editButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BUTTONS_WIDTH, BUTTONS_HEIGHT));
    editButton.addActionListener(new editButtonListener());
    deleteButton = new JButton("Delete person");
    deleteButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BUTTONS_WIDTH, BUTTONS_HEIGHT));

    /** Separator */
    separatorH = new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL);
    separatorH.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2,2));

    tablePanel.add(table.getTableHeader());
    tablePanel.add(scrollPane);

    buttonsPanel.add(addButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 3)));
    buttonsPanel.add(editButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 3)));
    buttonsPanel.add(deleteButton);

    /** Relocate compoments */
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,2,2,0);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    mainPanel.add(titleLabel, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    mainPanel.add(separatorH, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    mainPanel.add(tablePanel, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.insets = new Insets(9,10,0,0);
    mainPanel.add(buttonsPanel, c);

    /** Activate Main Frame and its properties */
    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
    mainFrame.setBounds(200, 100, 0, 0);
    mainFrame.setResizable(true);
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public class addButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        ((MyTableModel)model).setValueAt("cos", "test", "email", 123124);
        new GUI();
    }
}
}
```

MyTableModel class

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

static private ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
Object[][] persons = new Object[personList.size()][4];

int row;
int col;
static String name;
static String surname;
String email;
static int telephone;
private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "E-mail",
                                "Telephone"};

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return columnNames[col];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return persons.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    for(int i=0; i<personList.size(); i++) {
        persons [i][0] = personList.get(i).name.toString(); 
        persons [i][1] = personList.get(i).surname.toString(); 
        persons [i][2] = personList.get(i).mail.toString();
        persons [i][3] = personList.get(i).telephone; 
    }
    return persons[row][col];
}

public void fire(Object value, int row, int col) {
    persons[row][col] = value;
}

public void setValueAt(String n, String s, String e, int t){
    name = n;
    surname = s;
    email = e;
    telephone = t;
    Person person = new Person(n, s, e, t);
    personList.add(person);
    }
}
```

Person class

```
public class Person {
String name;
String surname;
String mail;
int telephone;

public Person(String n, String s, String m, int t){
    name = n;
    surname = s;
    mail = m;
    telephone = t;
}
}
```

Comment: See edit to answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table model is broken:

- You've got strange duplication of data with both an ArrayList as well as a 2D array. Get rid of the 2D Object array completely, and just use the ArrayList, a field that should **not** be static.
- You need to give this class an `addRow(Person p)` method, and in that method add another Person to the ArrayList, and call the `fireTableRowsInserted(...)` method, passing in the correct data. This is the method that should be called from your add ActionListener.
- Or make it much easier on yourself and don't use an ArrayList at all, and instead extend DefaultTableModel, and use its methods. This would be so much simpler and easier, and is what I'd do.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableFun extends JPanel {
    public static final String[] COL_NAMES = { "First Name", "Last Name", "E-mail", "Telephone" };
    private MyTableModel2 model = new MyTableModel2(COL_NAMES);
    private JTable myTable = new JTable(model);

    public TableFun() {
        JButton addPersonBtn = new JButton(new AddPersonAction("Add Person"));
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(addPersonBtn);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(myTable));
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class AddPersonAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddPersonAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String name = "John";
            String surname = "Smith";
            String address = "Foo Street";
            String telephone = "222-222-5555";
            model.addRow(new Person(name, surname, address, telephone));
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TableFun mainPanel = new TableFun();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Fun");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private class MyTableModel2 extends DefaultTableModel {
        public MyTableModel2(String[] columnNames) {
            super(columnNames, 0);
        }

        public void addRow(Person person) {
            Object[] rowData = new Object[4];
            rowData[0] = person.getName();
            rowData[1] = person.getSurname();
            rowData[2] = person.getMail();
            rowData[3] = person.getTelephone();            
            super.addRow(rowData);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (getRowCount() > 0) {
                Object value = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
                if (value != null) {
                    return value.getClass(); 
                }
            }
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String mail;
    private String telephone;

    public Person(String n, String s, String m, String t) {
        name = n;
        surname = s;
        mail = m;
        telephone = t;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }


}
```

Note that your own code could work if you de-cluttered it as suggested:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<Person1> personList = new ArrayList<Person1>();
    private String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "E-mail", "Telephone" };

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return personList.size(); //!! 
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Person1 person = personList.get(row);
        switch (col) {
        case 0:
            return person.name;
        case 1:
            return person.surname;
        case 2:
            return person.mail;
        case 3: 
            return person.telephone;
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void setValueAt(String n, String s, String e, int t) {
        Person1 person = new Person1(n, s, e, t);
        personList.add(person);
        int firstRow = personList.size() - 1;
        int lastRow = firstRow;
        fireTableRowsInserted(firstRow, lastRow);
    }
}
```